# mov fileName - error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, nasm

Hi have a program in NASM and in this part of the code

```
section .data
fileName dq 1

section .text
global _start
_start:
    xor rax, rax
    xor rcx, rcx
    xor rdx, rdx
    xor rbx, rbx
    mov rbx, rsp
    mov fileName, qword [rbx+16]
    push rsp
```

i have the error

```
test.asm:59: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

and the line 59 is `mov fileName, qword [rbx+16]`

Why is it wrong? And how can i solve it?

Comment: @Carcigenicate: You cannot have two explicit memory operands for the same instruction.

Comment: It’s hard to tell what it should be without seeing what comes next. [rbx+16] is argv[1]. Probably you want two instructions: `mov rax, [rbx+16]; mov [fileName], rax`

Comment: Note that rax was cleared a few lines before. If subsequent code needs rax to be 0, you need to move the xor instruction after using rax with the filename.

Comment: @prl yeah i did that !! Thank you

Comment: If this is setup for a system call, `syscall` doesn't care about RCX.  And Linux `int 0x80` is the 32-bit compat ABI, only using 32-bit pointers so you can't pass it stack addresses.  Also, `xor ebx,ebx` before `mov rbx, rsp` is redundant; you're already overwriting it.  Also, you could just `mov rax, [rsp+16]` instead of messing around with RBX first.